# Locating images uniquely when img ids are dynamic and src same for multiple images

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have 3 custom dropdowns which open when clicked on "down arrow" image appended at the end, Code for the image is something like :

```
<img id="x-auto-2017" class="x-form-trigger x-form-trigger-arrow " 
src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==">
```

Image id are dynamic and are in order of like 2017, 2018 etc. So I cannot use contains and identify them uniquely.

I want to get them clicked one by one and select value from the dropdown. Please help how to identify them uniquely.

Comment: What do you mean you want to get them clicked one by one?

Comment: If their position is ordered in the HTML page you could use the position qualifier `[N]` with `N=1...3` right after the XPath expression locating the first one.

Comment: @rsahai91 I meant, I want to click one at a time and select a corresponding value from the dropdown list

Comment: `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[contains(@id,'x-auto-']"));` it will return all webelements which contains 'x-auto-' in their id attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response, I used the position qualifier [N] as suggested by @Marcus, though have to hit and trial a bit but writing manual xpath on Chrome console I got the following answer to my query.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//img[starts-with(@id,'x-auto-2')])[2]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work for you:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[contains(@class,'x-form-trigger x-form-trigger-arrow']"));
        System.out.println("Number of drop downs on the page: " + elements.size());

        for (WebElement ele : elements) {
            ele.click();
            //Do what ever you want 
        }
```